# set font-size of element to be multiple of a font-size of another element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to set the font-size of an element to be a multiple of another element's font-size using JavaScript or CSS?

For example, if I have

```
.root {
   font-size: 10pt;
}
```

And I want to make the font-size another element to be multiple of this, so that it can be something like

```
.leaf {
   font-size: font-size-of-.root * 2.5;
}
```

I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //var leaf = document.getElementsByClassName("leaf")[0];
        $('.leaf').css({
            "font-size": function() {
                return $(".root").css('font-size') * 2.5;
            }
        });
    });
```

But it is not setting the font-size accordingly.

Comment: did you alert `$(".root").css('font-size')` and checked ?? ..if you had done then you must be knowing where's the actual problem

Comment: The issue is that css('font-size') returns lke '10px' instead of intended 10. That's why it does not work. You could wrap the $(".root").css('font-size') inside a parseInt() and then you would get the correct value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the element's font-size using `css()` method and multiply it with the factor you want:

```js
$('.big').css('font-size', parseInt($('.small').css('font-size')) * 2.5 + 'px');
```

```css
.small { font-size:10px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="small">Small font</span>
<span class="big">Big font</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also make `.leaf` a child of `.root` element -

```
<p class="root">
  Big
  <span class="leaf">Small</span>
</p>
```

And then use following css -

```
.root{
  font-size: 32px;
}
.leaf{
  font-size: 50%;
}
```